# iOS Datepicker: How to LOCK invalid dates?

Tags: ios, locking, uidatepicker, minimum

I've been struggling with the maximum/minimum date lately, and honestly, I don't know what I'm missing here. I searched a lot and no one seems to complain about it. (I'm not talking about setting a maximum/minimum date as these can only make invalid dates appear gray)

Here's what I've done so far:

```
    [myDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(disableDate) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then, on disableDate, I have something like this:

```
if ([myDatePicker.date compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        MyDatePicker.date = [NSDate date];
    }
```

(Or ascending, it depends on which dates I want to disable)

The thing is: it works fine but only ONCE. In other words: as soon as I open the view and try to pick, for example, 2007, it scrolls back to 2013. Great. But right after that, if I try to scroll to any invalid date (including 2007), it won't scroll back anymore until I reopen my view.
I feel like I'm missing something simple here, but I don't know what.

Thanks a lot in advance!

PS: Just to mention, I've put this inside disableDate

```
    NSLog(@"Value changed");
```

just to make sure it's calling the method everytime I scroll the datepicker, and yes, it is working;

PS2: I've tried the same but using

```
- (IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(id) sender
```

instead and it had exactly the same behaviour.

Comment: Tyr using `[myDatePicker reloadInputViews];` after setting the date.

Comment: Actually it did! I was making a mistake before! thank you SO much!!

Comment: I added my comment as an answer. If you want you can mark it as accepted answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in order to "reset" the `UIDatePicker` you can use `reloadInputViews` method (since `UIDatePicker` is subclass of `UIResponder`

Edit: spelling