# UIDatePicker constraints not working in device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

I am using UIDatePicker control in my project.  Added the UIDatePicker in xib file, and programmatically setting the constraints such as minimumDate, maximumDate to the datePicker.  This is working fine in simulator, but in device I am able to select any date in datePicker.

Sample code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.datePicker setMinimumDate:[NSDate date]];
    [self.datePicker setMaximumDate:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:3*24*60*60]];
}
```

screenshot:

[image: Here, i am able to select the previous dates also.]

Note: I am working on xcode5 - DP6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In what part of your code are you setting the minimum and maximum dates?

Comment: it'l works fine,,check your IBOutlet connection.

Comment: My question updated, please check.

Comment: @Sunny, in simulator it is working fine, but not in device.  The screen is taken from device, even i am not able to take screen shot from simulator, because it is not allowing me to select the above date in simulator.

Comment: i checked in device working fine i'm using xcode4.5

Comment: @Sunny, I checking in xcode5-DP6 and xcode4.5.1 and both are showing like this strange behaviour. First time selecting a invalid date in device is not allowing but second time onwards I am able to select in device.

Comment: hi reference : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598154/ios-datepicker-how-to-lock-invalid-dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an action for the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event on the `UIDatePicker` and implement checks to see if the selected date is greater than maximum date or less then the minimum date and set the date accordingly, like so:

```
- (IBAction)dateValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSTimeInterval date = [self.datePicker.date timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSTimeInterval maxmimumDate = [self.datePicker.maximumDate timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSTimeInterval minimumDate = [self.datePicker.minimumDate timeIntervalSince1970];

    if (date < minimumDate) {
        self.datePicker.date = self.datePicker.minimumDate;
    }

    if (date > maxmimumDate) {
        self.datePicker.date = self.datePicker.maximumDate;
    }

    // Use the selected date
    NSLog(@"%@", self.datePicker.date);
}
```

This will cause the `UIDatePicker` to scroll to the max/min date if you select a date outside the range.

Comment: This is custom validation in valueChanged event.  But, how can we handle this with minimumDate, maximumDate properties of UIDatePicker?

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the UIDatePicker whereby subsequent attempts to set a date outside of the minimumDate-maximumDate range succeed when they should fail. The code above works around this bug by forcing the selected date to lower/upper bounds of the acceptable date range.